# Automatically define height by content with iframe

Tags: iframe

```
<iframe frameborder="0" style="height: 1800px; overflow:scroll; width: 100%" src="https://merch.streamelements.com/benjuna" marginheight="1" marginwidth="1" name="cboxmain" id="cboxmain" seamless="seamless" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

If I set the height to "auto" it only shows the top banner, if I lock it to a certain amount of pixels then the page does not work on smaller screens.
Any thoughts about this?

Answer (score 0):

Here, this makes it take up the entire page you still have to scrol but it fills the page :

```
<iframe 
    style="
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%; "
    frameborder="0" 
    src="https://merch.streamelements.com/benjuna" 
    marginheight="1" 
    marginwidth="1" 
    name="cboxmain" 
    id="cboxmain" 
    seamless="seamless"  
    frameborder="0" 
    allowtransparency="true">
</iframe>
```

Comment: https://benjuna.no/merch/

Sadly, it does not work.